# ReportViewer Shows Empty Rows

Tags: c#, vb.net, rdlc, reportviewer, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I'm using Dynamic DataSet (NewDs) which is connected with datatable(xtbl) but Reportviewer Shows Rows without Text
here is my code, Any Problem???

```
    Dim f4 As New Form4 
    Dim ds2 As New NewDS   ***NewDS=Dataset

    Dim xtbl As New DataTable
    
    xtbl = CType(DgvEmp.DataSource, DataTable)
    ds2.Reset
    ds2.DataSetName = "newTable"
    'xtbl.TableName = "DSxtbl"
    ds2.Tables.Add(xtbl.Copy)
    ds2.Tables(0).TableName="DT"
    Dim rds As New ReportDataSource(ds2.Tables(0).TableName ,ds2.Tables(0) ) 
    f4.reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local
    f4.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear
    f4.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh
    f4.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)
    f4.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource="EmployeeBouncer.Report2.rdlc"

    f4.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh
    f4.ReportViewer1.Refresh
    f4.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport
    
    f4.Show
```

Comment: Do you understand what happens when you include the `New` keyword in a variable declaration?

Answer (score 0):

try with below code

```
Dim f4 As New Form4 
    Dim ds2 As New NewDS   ***NewDS=Dataset
    Dim xtbl As New DataTable    
    xtbl = CType(DgvEmp.DataSource, DataTable)
    ds2.Tables.Add(xtbl)
f4.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource="EmployeeBouncer.Report2.rdlc"
  Dim rds As New ReportDataSource("dt",ds2.Tables(0)) // Dataset name "dt" should be same as in rdlc file.
  f4.reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local
  f4.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear
  f4.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)  
  f4.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh
  f4.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport
 ~~~
```

Comment: Can edit your answer to offer an explanation of what this codes doing?

Comment: I've Tried but Same Problem

Comment: @Addullah, there are couple of things you can try. 1)  change ReportEmbeddedResource with ReportPath. 2) Verify rdlc file name and path 3) Check ds2.Tables(0) is not null and have records 4) Dataset name in Report2.rdlc should be "dt" .

Comment: did it but nothing change :(